# a null reference error in c# return statement

Tags: c#

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var c = obj as myObj;
    if (c == null) return false;

    return   this.Id.Equals(c.Id)
        && this.Email.Equals(c.Email)
        && this.code.Equals(c.code)
        && (this.myVal == null) ? true : (this.myVal.Equals(c.myVal))
}
```

This method as shown is supposed to return a boolean. When the value in "this.myVal" is null, I just want to return true (which I am doing above). Instead I get an
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" caused in the check for this.myVal. This error indicates that the C# compiler does not care for my "null" check? Why should it complain about the null reference?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler, it's a runtime exception. Can you post the exact stack trace?

Comment: btw, are you sure that Id, Email and code are not null?

Comment: Can you provide stack trace? it's hard to determine **which** object reference is not set without it.

Comment: What is the type of myVal? and did you override its Equals operator too?

Comment: the value that I am deliberately setting to null is "myVal". No other fields are null. myVal is a string type. the error thrown is System.nullReference Exception. Object reference not set to an instance of the object. c.myVal is null as well. I did not override the == operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is caused by the order of operations.  You're expecting this:

```
x && y && z && (foo == null ? true : foo.Whatever())
```

But what you're actually getting is this:

```
(x && y && z && foo == null) ? true : foo.Whatever()
```

Put the ternary operator inside of parentheses to ensure that it executes the way you expect it to.

Comment: Cole Campbell: Do you mean like this:(x && y && z && foo == null ?) true : foo.Whatever()

Comment: No.  That code won't compile.  My first example is what you want:  put the entire ternary operator inside of parentheses (x ? y : z).

Comment: Or simpler still, avoid the pointless ternary operator here altogether and write (this.myVal == null || this.myVal.Equals(c.myVal))